# How to filter users by assigned plan using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying the request below. Filtering users by their servicePlanId in assignedPlans property, trying to filter "Phone System" plan.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$filter=assignedPlans/any(x:x/servicePlanId eq 4828c8ec-dc2e-4779-b502-87ac9ce28ab7)
```

And receiving the error message given below inside response body.

```
"message": "Complex query on property assignedPlans is not supported.",
```

[MS-Graph-Explorer link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=users%3F%24filter%3DassignedPlans%2Fany(x%3Ax%2FservicePlanId%20eq%204828c8ec-dc2e-4779-b502-87ac9ce28ab7)&method=GET&version=beta&GraphUrl=https://graph.microsoft.com)
How can i filter users in this way? And is there any way i can achieve this using ms-graph-java-sdk?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a limitation of the current APIs. [There a newer engine](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/identity/blogs/microsoft-graph-advanced-queries-for-directory-objects-are-now-generally-available/) that allows for more complex queries. To access it you need to add the `ConsistencyLevel` header with the value `eventual` and add `$count=true` as a query parameter.

[Here is a link to the graph explorer with the new query](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=users%3F%24filter%3DassignedPlans%2Fany(x%3Ax%2FservicePlanId%20eq%204828c8ec-dc2e-4779-b502-87ac9ce28ab7)%26%24count%3Dtrue&method=GET&version=v1.0&GraphUrl=https://graph.microsoft.com&headers=W3sibmFtZSI6IkNvbnNpc3RlbmN5TGV2ZWwiLCJ2YWx1ZSI6ImV2ZW50dWFsIn1d)

Comment: Thank you so much! How my i add ConsistencyLevel header using sdk?

Comment: i am using java 1.8

Comment: graphClient.users().buildRequest(new HeaderOption("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual")).count().filter("assignedPlans/any").get()