# Graph api find users with a specific assigned plan and return only those plans

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to minimize the results given by a query.
I know that this [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=id,displayName,assignedPlans&$filter=assignedPlans/any(u:u/service+eq+'PowerAppsService'+and+a/capabilityStatus+eq+'Enabled')&$count=true](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=id,displayName,assignedPlans&$filter=assignedPlans/any(u:u/service+eq+%27PowerAppsService%27+and+a/capabilityStatus+eq+%27Enabled%27)&$count=true)

Returns all the licenses of the users that have any kind of active PowerApps plan
But what I would really like is that the assignedPlans array that comes also filtered in the response for the same criteria.

So, instead the complete list:

```
...
                {
                    "assignedDateTime": "2022-10-28T14:30:14Z",
                    "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
                    "service": "MicrosoftCommunicationsOnline",
                    "servicePlanId": "3e26ee1f-8a5f-4d52-aee2-b81ce45c8f40"
                },
                {
                    "assignedDateTime": "2022-10-28T14:30:14Z",
                    "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
                    "service": "PowerAppsService",
                    "servicePlanId": "9c0dab89-a30c-4117-86e7-97bda240acd2"
                },
                {
                    "assignedDateTime": "2022-10-28T14:30:14Z",
                    "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
                    "service": "MicrosoftOffice",
                    "servicePlanId": "531ee2f8-b1cb-453b-9c21-d2180d014ca5"
                },
...
```

I only this one for each user:

```
        {
            "assignedDateTime": "2022-10-28T14:30:14Z",
            "capabilityStatus": "Enabled",
            "service": "PowerAppsService",
            "servicePlanId": "9c0dab89-a30c-4117-86e7-97bda240acd2"
        }
```

Tried to expand and filter, but then I received this error message:

> [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=id,displayName&$filter=assignedPlans/any(x:x/service+eq+'PowerAppsService'+and+a/capabilityStatus+eq+'Enabled')&$expand=assignedPlans($filter=service+eq+'PowerAppsService'+and+a/capabilityStatus+eq+'Enabled')&$count=true](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=id,displayName&$filter=assignedPlans/any(x:x/service+eq+%27PowerAppsService%27+and+a/capabilityStatus+eq+%27Enabled%27)&$expand=assignedPlans($filter=service+eq+%27PowerAppsService%27+and+a/capabilityStatus+eq+%27Enabled%27)&$count=true)
>
> Parsing OData Select and Expand failed: Property 'assignedPlans' on
> type 'microsoft.graph.user' is not a navigation property or complex
> property. Only navigation properties can be expanded.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you check this similar question for the query for particular user:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65919279/how-to-filter-users-by-assigned-plan-using-microsoft-graph-api

Comment: @MehtabSiddique this doesn't help, as mentioned, the query works, the issue is with filtering the output.